# Why does multi-threaded rendering not use all the CPU potential in QGIS 2.4?

Tags: qgis, multithreading

I have just downloaded QGIS 2.4 which is great and ran some tests. I have enabled the multi-threaded rendering but it seems that the program do not use all the potential of my CPU. Attached pic shows CPU usage when QGIS is rendering (top) and some other multi-threaded program I am using. As You can see the "other" program takes all the cores to a 100% while QGIS only took half of them. The rendering time in this case was 78586 ms, so it's not like it couldn't be any faster. Max cores to use is set to 8. Is this normal or am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: What other data can you provide? Stuff like datasource, map styles, etc are handy to know.  Could you also run it though my program qgis2img to get some render benchmarks https://github.com/DMS-Aus/qgis2img

Comment: I'm also not sure I would want it to use 100% CPU, I normally have other things going on at the same time.

Comment: The data loaded is alot of relatively big point, line and polygon shapefiles. All stylized differently. I would gladly provide more data but don't know what else might be useful. Also i don't really have the knowledge to run the program you provided. I sometimes get to work with big data sets so it would be cool to use all of the CPU potential if that meant super fast rendering. And judging by the current rendering speeds and CPU usage ratio, it would actualy be super fast with all the cores working at 100%.

Comment: Maybe I/O is the bottle neck for QGIS here because it's not getting enough data to render at 100%.  I'll update the wiki for the project to show you how to run it on Windows.